# AIO not found while compiling nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, config, aio

I am trying to compile nginx on ubuntu and I am using the following config parameters:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/share/nginx \
  --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
  --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
  --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
  --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
  --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body \
  --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi \
  --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy \
  --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi \
  --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi \
  --with-debug \
  --with-pcre-jit \
  --with-http_ssl_module \
  --with-http_stub_status_module \
  --with-http_realip_module \
  --with-http_auth_request_module \
  --with-http_addition_module \
  --with-http_dav_module \
  --with-http_geoip_module \
  --with-http_gzip_static_module \
  --with-http_sub_module \
  --with-http_v2_module \
  --with-stream \
  --with-stream_ssl_module \
  --with-stream_ssl_preread_module \
  --with-threads \
  --with-file-aio \
  --without-mail_pop3_module \
  --without-mail_smtp_module \
  --without-mail_imap_module \
  --without-http_uwsgi_module \
  --without-http_scgi_module \
  --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/ngx_devel_kit-$NDK_VERSION" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/set-misc-nginx-module-$SETMISC_VERSION" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/nginx-module-vts-$VTS_VERSION" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/lua-nginx-module-$LUA_VERSION" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/headers-more-nginx-module-$MORE_HEADERS_VERSION" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/nginx-goodies-nginx-sticky-module-ng-$STICKY_SESSIONS_VERSION" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/nginx-http-auth-digest-$NGINX_DIGEST_AUTH" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module-$NGINX_SUBSTITUTIONS" \
  --add-module="$BUILD_PATH/lua-upstream-nginx-module-$LUA_UPSTREAM_VERSION" || exit 1 \
  && make || exit 1 \
  && make install || exit 1
```

Now, when I am trying to compile it, here is the error I am getting:

```
checking for gcc -pipe switch ... found
checking for -Wl,-E switch ... not found
checking for gcc builtin atomic operations ... not found
checking for C99 variadic macros ... not found
checking for gcc variadic macros ... not found
checking for gcc builtin 64 bit byteswap ... not found
checking for unistd.h ... found
checking for inttypes.h ... found
checking for limits.h ... found
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for sys/param.h ... found
checking for sys/mount.h ... found
checking for sys/statvfs.h ... found
checking for crypt.h ... found
checking for Linux specific features
checking for epoll ... not found
checking for O_PATH ... not found
checking for sendfile() ... not found
checking for sendfile64() ... not found
checking for sys/prctl.h ... found
checking for prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) ... not found
checking for sched_setaffinity() ... not found
checking for crypt_r() ... not found
checking for sys/vfs.h ... found
checking for nobody group ... not found
checking for nogroup group ... found
checking for poll() ... not found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for crypt() in libcrypt ... not found
checking for F_READAHEAD ... not found
checking for posix_fadvise() ... not found
checking for O_DIRECT ... not found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for statfs() ... not found
checking for statvfs() ... not found
checking for dlopen() ... not found
checking for dlopen() in libdl ... not found
checking for sched_yield() ... not found
checking for sched_yield() in librt ... not found
checking for SO_SETFIB ... not found
checking for SO_REUSEPORT ... not found
checking for SO_ACCEPTFILTER ... not found
checking for SO_BINDANY ... not found
checking for IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT ... not found
checking for IP_TRANSPARENT ... not found
checking for IP_BINDANY ... not found
checking for IP_RECVDSTADDR ... not found
checking for IP_PKTINFO ... not found
checking for IPV6_RECVPKTINFO ... not found
checking for TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT ... not found
checking for TCP_KEEPIDLE ... not found
checking for TCP_FASTOPEN ... not found
checking for TCP_INFO ... not found
checking for accept4() ... not found
checking for kqueue AIO support ... not found
checking for Linux AIO support ... not found
checking for Linux AIO support (SYS_eventfd) ... not found

./configure: no supported file AIO was found
Currently file AIO is supported on FreeBSD 4.3+ and Linux 2.6.22+ only
```

Now, when I remove the -with-cc-opt line, I don't get this error and it find the AIO. I am installing libaio1 and libaio-dev, so the libraries are there, still I am getting this error. Can you please help me figure it out. TIA.

Comment: This is almost exactly what's in here: http://serverfault.com/questions/636538/errors-when-compiling-nginx-with-pagespeed-on-centos-7 .  Only, your version apparently has the correct `--with-cc-opt` line.  Maybe the way you're running this script is somehow breaking that long line on you?

Comment: i just had this issue, and it was a missing quote in my `--with-cc-opt` command, does this help? I know this is a good 4 years late

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the *no supported file AIO was found* error, you need to run;

```sh
# use apt where apt-get is not available or applicable
sudo apt-get install libaio
```

Comment: The above problem happens even with this installed.

Comment: @PKHunter please share the content of your configuration script, server version and error output. You can use [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/) as it may all not fit within comment owing to character limit. Remember not to include any personal information.

Comment: Thanks @nyedidikeke. My issue is now different. I ended up finding all the required libraries, including AIO. There's a ton of them that are not in the official documentation. Anyway, now the modules build, but when I move them into the `/usr/share/nginx/modules/` folder (and not the usual `/etc/nginx/modules` folder found in docs), I see this error:  

`nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_security_headers_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Just to add, the `./configure` script is here: https://gist.github.com/pkiula/c498caaa01ff14e49e4071a4d15f7fec

Answer (score 0):

AIO support needs the header `linux/aio_abi.h`, which is contained in the `linux-headers` package.